# Why is my theme function not called (not in template file)?

Tags: 7, theming

I have a simple theme and everything is by documentation/examples:

```
function activit_theme() {

  return array(

      'activit_package_teaser' => array(
          'arguments' => array('node' => NULL),
          'type' => 'module'
      ),

  );
}
```

+

```
function theme_activit_package_teaser($node) {

  $output = '
    <div class="package-teaser">
      package  
    </div>
  ';

  return $output;
}
```

and

```
function activit_packages_block() {

  $nids = db_select('node', 'n')->fields('n', array('nid', 'status'));
  $nids->join('field_data_field_important', 'f', 'f.entity_id = n.nid');
  $nids->fields('f', array('field_important_value', 'entity_id'));
  $nids->condition('n.status', 1)->condition('f.field_important_value', 1);
  $nids = $nids->execute()->fetchCol();

  $nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);

  $packages = '';
  foreach($nodes as $node) {
    $packages .= theme('activit_package_teaser', array('node' => $node));
  }

  return '
    <div class="important-packages wrapper">
      <h2>'.t('Important packages').'</h2>

      <div class="cont">
        '.$packages.'
      </div>    
    </div>
  ';

}
```

there are 4 nodes, but my theme is not called at all and nothing is inserted into `<div class="cont"></div>`. No error in "recent log messages".  Why it does not work?

---

**UPDATE:** When the template is in activit_package_teaser.tpl file it works:

```
  'activit_package_teaser' => array(
      'arguments' => array('node' => NULL),
      'template' => 'activit_package_teaser',
      'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'activit') . '/templates/',
  ),
```

But why it does not work as a theme function?

Answer (score 0):

`arguments` was for Drupal 6, you need to use `variables` for Drupal 7.  One of `variables` or `render element` is required, hence nothing is showing up at the moment as the item isn't making it into the theme registry.

```
function activit_theme() {

  return array(

      'activit_package_teaser' => array(
          'variables' => array('node' => NULL),
          'type' => 'module'
      ),

  );
}
```

Comment: That's weird because now I have the theme html in .tpl file and it works even if i still use `arguments`. Check update of my question.

Comment: Clear the caches, the changes won't be picked up until you do. It definitely shouldn't work with `arguments` if you have a non-modified Drupal 7 core, the docs say as much. If they're wrong it's a bug :)

Comment: I cleared the cahce multiple times... I just checked my previous projects and realised that in every project I've made (D7) I used `arguments` and file template. It is the way I am used to. It allways worked. I also tried what you said - to use `variables` but it still just does not work when the theme is defined as a function `theme_activit_package_teaser()` :(

Comment: I also noticed than my custom module is in 'activit' folder and the same name has the folder where my theme is. Maybe that is the problem.